# Take data from custom attribute to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form for countries. The fields are `country` and `country_code`.

The first field will e the `country_code` which for example is DE for Germany, IT for Italy, NL for Netherlands.

Now the field for `country_code` has a custom attribute with the full name;

```
<option data-country="Netherlands" value="NL">NL</option>
```

I now want that once the `country_code` has been selected the other input(for country) Will be filled with `data-country="Netherlands"` attribute. So the users don't have to write the full country name.

For my example I'd like to use `jQuery`, but I honestly have no idea where to start. Nor do I have an idea if I'm going in the right direction with this.

questions:

A) Am I thinking in the right direction?

B) How can I achieve the result I want in the easiest way?

C) Are there any alternative ways of doing this?

Codeblock:

```
<!-- Country_short input -->
<select id="country_code" name="country_code">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a Country Code</option>
    <option data-country="Netherlands" value="NL">NL</option>
    <option data-country="Germany" value="DE">DE</option>
</select>

<!-- Country input -->
<label for="country">Country</label>
<input id="country" class="" type="text" value="" name="country">

<!-- Button -->
<button type="submit">Start Ticket</button>
```

Comment: Please post relevant HTML. It is impossible to derive a solution by looking at just one line.

Comment: @31piy Added a code block with the form for you

Comment: @mike updated answer based on your updated question

Comment: @mike As per your need 'So the users don't have to write the full country name', keep the input as disabled or make use of other tags to display the country name. So that users don't have any confusion on what to do with the editable input field.

Comment: @Praveen Thank you that's a perfect idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow some steps for that:

1. Assign a `change` event to `country_code` dropdown
2. Then when a `option` is selected or changed, you need to look for the selected option so that you can get the `data` attribute `country` which is `data-country`.
3. Now, you can set this value to the `country` element where you want to show it.

```js
$('#country_code').change(function() {
  var countryName = $('#country_code option:selected').data('country');
  $('#country').val(countryName);
  $('[for="country"]').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country_code" name="country_code">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a Country Code</option>
  <option data-country="Netherlands" value="NL">NL</option>
  <option data-country="Germany" value="DE">DE</option>
</select>

<!-- Country input -->
<label for="country">Country</label>
<input id="country" class="" type="text" value="" name="country">

<!-- Button -->
<button type="submit">Start Ticket</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, that does exactly what I want it to do! Accepted your answer